# TypeKit vs NSAttributedString - can I use TextKit as a replacement for NSAttributedString when creating styled labels?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, nsattributedstring, textkit

I want to style a label. Nothing crazy, just some coloring, changing of font-sizes for specific words, etc. I can do this with NSAttributedString, but would it be possible/better to do in TextKit, newly introduced with iOS 7?

I've looked around, but TextKit doesn't yet have a ton of tutorials, and none seem to address this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should still be done with `NSAttributedStrings` as the parameters you've listed exactly describe the **attributes** of **strings**. `NSTextStorage` is a subclass of `NSMutableAttributedString` but it's not intended for what you want to do (I think this class might have misled you).

[Using Text Kit to Draw and Manage Text](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/CustomTextProcessing/CustomTextProcessing.html) contains a nice overview of Text Kit objects, I highly recommend reading it.